# Dynamically loaded slider using bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have the following design for a carousel slider

The first slide has a larger main image (and 4 smaller)
[image: The first slide has a larger main image]

The second slide is split between 8 smaller images
[image: The second slide is split between 8 smaller images]

The screenshots attached were built using bootstrap - something like this

```html
<div class="item active">
 <div class="col-xs-6 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img01">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img02">
  <img src="~/img03">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img04">
  <img src="~/img05">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img06">
  <img src="~/img07">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img08">
  <img src="~/img09">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img01">
  <img src="~/img02">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 grid-col">
  <img src="~/img03">
  <img src="~/img04">
 </div>
</div>
```

Of course that was easy! Now I need to dynamically load my images it's got a lot more complicated.....

This is how my razor markup looks currently

```html
<div class="listing-slider-grid">
    <div class="row grid-row" id="listingSlider">
        <div id="carouselListingSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
            <div class="carousel-inner" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".carousel-modal">
                @foreach (var slide in Model.ListingSliderImages.ToArray().Split(8))
                {
                    <div class="item @(firstItemInSlider ? "active" : "")">
                        @foreach (var row in slide.ToArray().Split(4))
                        {
                            <div class="row">
                                @foreach (var item in row)
                                {
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <img class="small-slider-img" src="~/images/optimisedImages/testing-slider-images/@item.ImageDefinition.Url">
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        }                        
                    </div>
                    firstItemInSlider = false;
                }
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselListingSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselListingSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on screen the two slides are looking like this

[image: slider1]

[image: slider2]

not too bad but I haven't managed to get that larger image in (and I have issues on slider two when there aren't enough images to populate a full slide).

I'm really stumped with how to get that first large image when rendering a list using the Bootstrap grid system (I've been using this helpful article https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/approaches-when-rendering-list-using-bootstrap-grid-system/)

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks, Sam

Comment: p.s would appreciate any upvotes, new here & trying to build reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make exception in the loop to set more width (xs-6) for that element:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in row)
{
    if([Your condition]) {
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="small-slider-img" src="~/images/optimisedImages/testing-slider-images/@item.ImageDefinition.Url">
        </div>
    } else { // Current behavior
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="small-slider-img" src="~/images/optimisedImages/testing-slider-images/@item.ImageDefinition.Url">
        </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

If you add an xs-6 you have to modify the rest of the row, so all of them never exceed 12 value (maximum columns per row)